# Restarting the loop using continue keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, what am doing here is taking a random number from the computer and asking user to guess what the random number might be, but I want this loop to go on until the user inputs the correct guess.

```
from random import randint

print("Lets start the game!! ")

x=randint(1,10)

print(x)

y=input("Enter your guess: ")

z=True

while z:    
  if x!=int(y):

    continue   
  else : 
    print("Correct Guess")

     break
```

I expected the continue loop, to restart the loop check again, but after even single inccorect input, even if I put the correct guess, the program aint working

Comment: What part of this code do you think would cause the computer to prompt the user again if they guessed wrongly the first time?  I.e., what will cause "input" to get called a 2nd time?

Comment: It looks like an infinite loop to me, unless `x == int(y)` the first time through.  If not, then your `continue` is executed, it goes back to the top of the loop, i.e. `while z`, `z` is still `True`, and `x != int(y)`, the `continue` is executed, and it never stops. In order for it to exit at that point, at least one of `z`, `x`, or `y` would have to change, but there's nothing inside your loop that could change them.  You do understand that the loop starts at `while z`, not the top of your file, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never ask for y again. It is always using the first input. Try asking again inside the loop like this:

```
from random import randint

print("Lets start the game!! ")

x = randint(1, 10)

print(x)

y = input("Enter your guess: ")

z = True

while z:
    y = input("Enter your guess: ")
    if x != int(y):
        continue
    else:
        print("Correct Guess")
        break
```

Comment: Thankyou very much :-D

Comment: If it worked can you mark as correct so other people with the same problem get some help too? @DeepanshuMaan